# USE statemet does not work in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I use **SQL tab** in phpMyAdmin to **test** statements, but some queries does not work, like, USE query; But, for example, after running USE statement and then using USE DATABASE() to check, null value returned.

```
USE dbname;
USE dbname
USE `dbname`;
```

I want to be able to run SQL statements on specific database; and this is possible after selecting (after using USE statement) database. I can click on the database name on the left sidebar and then run SQL statements, I know; But why is not possible to use "USE" statement to select database directly?

Comment: I am not using phpmyadmin for the last two years. But i know this worked. So I tested this on phpmyadmin demo website and it worked fine

Comment: What are you expecting the `USE` query to return?

Comment: @Milk - I want to be able to run SQL statements on specific database; and this is possible after selecting (after using USE statement) database. After USE statement, I expect return database name when run SELECT DATABASE().
I can click on the database name on the left sidebar and then run SQL statements, I know; But why is not possible to use "USE" statement to select database directly?

Answer (score 0):

The `USE` statement doesn't return anything. This is why you are seeing `null`. It is functioning correctly.

`USE` sets the connection to use the database in the statement for future statements.